# How to upload file to google drive using jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I want to add stage with one step to my Jenkinsfile pipeline to upload an apk to google drive and then getting the shareable link of uploaded file.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked [this](https://github.com/general-mobile/jenkins-google-drive-uploader)? Looks like it could be of some use